# Why am I seeing these messages when I try to update with 22.04 (Jammy jellyfish?)

Tags: updates

This is what is happening after I updated to 22.04 LTS

```
me@me-desktop:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for me: 
Get:1 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x jammy InRelease                                                           
Hit:3 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                     
Hit:4 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 270 kB in 1s (210 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
67 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/i18n/Translation-en_AU' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'hippo/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'hippo' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
me@me-desktop:~$
```

Why is hippo still listed?

Comment: So you've upgraded from 21.04, right? Can you post the contents of your sources.list file? (/etc/apt/sources.list)

Comment: I did look through that and deleted any entry with hippo in it.
If I post the list, it is going to be a "dogs breakfast".
I've tried to post formatted things here, but it doesn't work.
How would I post it reply so it is readable?
If my deleting the "hippo" files would/should fit it, that's ok.

Comment: That seems to have got rid of the "hippo" references, so all is good.
How do I mark this as SOLVED/RESOLVED?